# React, Jest - Cannot run test together

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using this libs:

- react 16.12.0
- jest 26.4.0
- react-testing-library 11.0.4
- react-testing-library/jest-dom 5.11.4

And I have this test:

```
describe('Test suite', () => {
    it('test1', async () => {
        const config =
            {
                settings: {
                    ...
                }
            };
        const view = render(<MyApp config={config}/>);
        const form = await screen.findByTestId(/form/i);
        expect(form).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(view.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('test2', async () => {
        const config =
            {
                settings: {
                    ...
                }
            };
        const view = render(<MyApp config={config}/>);
        const form = await screen.findByTestId(/form/i);
        expect(form).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(view.asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

When I run **test1** and **test2** like single test run, everything is ok. But if I run **Test suite**, **test1** is ok and **test2** failed, cause config object is undefined. Could anyone help me with this?

Tried:

- `afterEach(cleanup)`

Comment: Can you change the order and check if second test is failing only?

Comment: I did it and everytime fails second test. It looks like, they are sharing something :(

Comment: Can you show what settings are you having in both?

Comment: Same JSON object:            
                    formSchemes: [
                        {
                            schema: {
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            uiSchema: {
                                "ui:widget": "DatePickerWidget"
                            },
                            formData: '2020-06-11'
                        }
                    ]

Comment: If your JSON's are identical, then why are you doing same test again! Only thing I can guess is, "test2" may be trying to compare with the snapshot created by "test1".

Comment: It's only for demonstration. Its not relevant. I need find out, when i run two same test, second one fails.

Comment: Okay... Can you try "beforeEach" instead rendering "MyApp" inside test and check please?

Comment: I need view object and different config in each test, i dont think that "beforeEach" can help me :(

Comment: Try to reproduce in a codesandbox

Comment: I tried, but i cannot reproduce in fullscope, cause MyApp components is so complex with co many async and lazy loading/code spliting.

Comment: It's look like problem with combination Jest + React.Suspense. In MyApp is Suspense with fallback and in second case(test2), Suspense component doest wait on all Promises and continue rendering App. :(